# Can pure-bosonic string theories exist in curved spacetime?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, ads-cft, tachyon

Question: Can there be a consistent non-supersymmetric pure-bosonic string theory in some curved spacetimes?

Reason: Since fields with certain amount of negative mass can exist in curved spacetime (cf. the Breitenlohner-Freedman bound in AdS) and since avoiding ground-state tachyons of  pure-bosonic strings in flat spacetime seems to be the main motivation (besides phenomenological reasons) for superstrings in flat spacetime.

Extending this, are there examples of consistent AdS/CFT dualities involving pure-bosonic fields in the bulk?

Comment: I deleted a few off-topic comments. Remember that comments are not the place to hold discussions; do that in [chat].

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for that tip, but there was a comment (archived at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/33243 ) from Lubos Motl where he gave a arXiv reference to a related paper that might have a partial answer. Can you please get it back?? (and once that is done, you can deleted this comment of mine and yours).

Comment: It was "For some examples of non-SUSY AdS/CFT examples that rely on the validity of the BF bound, try e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0105047 - a problem is that the paper is in 'SUGRA' only. The critical dimensions aren't imposed in general and the CFTs are only described rather vaguely by some operators and properties." Let me know when you've seen it. In the future, remember to save any important information in comments (possibly by editing it into the post, or turning it into an answer) while the comments are still fresh.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks. But I (and others) can follow the archived copy at the physicsoverflow link and see Lubos Motl message. But my point was, why would anyone have to delete such a comment in the first place?! Do you have the power to un-delete that comment by Motl? If you can bring it back, we can delete all of these unreleated conversations between us!

Comment: The comments get deleted because useful information goes in the question or in answers. That's part of the reason Stack Exchange exists: get people to the information they want (the answer) without distractions (comments). If you think the link is useful, I encourage you to turn it into an answer.

Comment: @DavidZ I have been on SEs (not just physics, but few others too) long enough to know what you are saying is not true. SE comments exist for a reason. What Motl wrote was not a full answer, and rightly deserves to stay a comment. And neither is it mine to incorporate it in my question itself (why would anyone even do that, even if its theirs is beyond me!).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64740/2451 and links therein.