# Symmetries on String theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, tachyon

Recently I was watching and reading about String theory, M-theory and the supersymmetry, when I remembered one question that I had while reading 'The Elegant Universe' by Brian Greene that is: why do the String theory need superpartners for all fermions and bosons from the standard model? I mean, for the little that I understand, supersymmetry **MUST** exists, because if not the String theory doesn't work or it's not possible. 
So, how really works, it's necessary for the String theory to be able to exist, or it just appears from the theory itself?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64740/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201782/2451 and links therein.

Comment: From what I understant it is a favored option see https://motls.blogspot.com/2010/06/why-string-theory-implies-supersymmetry.html  . Long blog, concludes  "Supersymmetry follows from string theory - the only way how to reconcile gravity and other forces described by renormalizable QFTs. Statistically speaking, low-energy supersymmetry seems to be a likely consequence of string-theoretical phenomenology, too"   seem and likely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can string theory work without supersymmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64740/how-can-string-theory-work-without-supersymmetry)